Shared Google Calendar, but contacts are now also shared
I shared my Google Calendar with my family member, and he also shared his with me. Now, however, all of our contacts are also shared with each other. I don't want our contacts shared. He has a lot (400+) and I don't want to see all of his contacts mixed in with mine.
Other solutions I have checked into don't seem to address this situation specifically. There has to be a setting somewhere that says 'don't share my contacts', but I can't find it.
I have a Samsung Galaxy A42 and my family member has a Samsung Galaxy A25.

How did you "share your calendars"? To me sound s more like you added your husband's Google account as secondary account on your phone.

menu>settings>Manage accounts>add account. I think this is how I added. And since you phrased it that way, perhaps this is what I did. But, this does not explain how/why the contacts are being shared, or how to break that link.  Thank you for your comment.

What you did was not sharing a Google calendar, instead you simply added a seconds Google Account to your Android device.
The seconds device of course then synced all calendar entries but as well all contacts als GMail messages.
You can see the categories sync is activated in Android settings of the account:
Menu -> Settings -> Manage accounts -> Select your husbend's Google account -> Synchronize Account -> For each sync category there is a switch for enabling/disabling sync.
Sharing only a calendar
Google provides a sync method that solely shares the calendar. This way is not available from the Google Calendar app, according to the Google Calendar sharing documentation it requires to use the web version of Google Calendar:

Share a calendar with specific people:
On your computer, open Google Calendar. You can’t share calendars from the Google Calendar app. On the left, find the “My calendars” section. To expand it, click the Down arrow Down arrow. Hover over the calendar you want to share, and click More More and then Settings and sharing.
Under “Share with specific people or groups,” click Add people and groups.
Add a person’s or Google group’s email address. Use the drop-down menu to adjust their permission settings. Learn more about access permissions.
Click Send. The recipient will need to click the emailed link to add
the calendar to their list.


YES! This is working as I want it to. Thank you so much. I see we were sharing everything Google. So I was able to drop that connection and share only the calendars. Thanks again.

@KathyKeil On Stackexchange you can say thank you by upvoting and accepting (the grey/green arrow below the up/downvote buttons. As this is an answer to your own question you should be able to do so even without having the necessary reputation score.
